# What do I do to include <X11/Xlocale.h> when compiling with emscripten?

Tags: c++, cmake, emscripten

I have code that depends on <X11/Xlocale.h>.  When I try to compile with the emscripten tool chain (after CMake generate), I get the following error.  What do I need to change in my configuration?

```
      'X11/Xlocale.h' file not found
#    include <X11/Xlocale.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I'm doing this on Linux.

```
$ uname -a
Linux bracket 4.10.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 20:20:37 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've confirmed I have libx-dev installed.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx11-dev is already the newest version (2:1.6.4-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: CMake should have probably complained, but how about installing the package which contains that file?

Comment: *What do I need to change in my configuration?* You need to show us your configuration first.

Comment: Updated.  What else should I report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emscripten can't use native libraries -- it's outputting Javascript code, after all; it can't use libraries which contain native x86 (or other architecture) code. As such, emscripten won't search for headers in your system's include directories, because a lot of those headers will describe functionality which isn't available to an Emscripten program. It uses internal search paths instead.

Now, `<X11/Xlocale.h>` is a bit of a weird header. It doesn't actually define anything; it just includes `<locale.h>`, so you may be able to get away with replacing `#include <X11/Xlocale.h>` with `#include <locale.h>`. However, if your application uses other X11 functionality, it may not be buildable under Emscripten.

Comment: Thanks.  I replaced with <locale.h> and got past that error.